# SymfonyでThe option "choice_list" does not exist.のエラー

Tags: php, symfony

Symfony2.3のシステムをSymfony3へアップデートし、動作を確認しております。
フォーム作成ページにアクセスしたところ、下記エラーが出ました。
Symfony3.0以降でchoice_listは使えなくなり、`choices`か`choice_loader`を試したのですが、typeが異なるようで、コードの変更をどのようにしていいか分かりません。
修正のアイデアをいただきたいです。

https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/reference/forms/types/choice.html#choice-list
**Error**

```
The option "choice_list" does not exist. Defined options are: "action", "allow_extra_fields", "allow_file_upload", "attr", "auto_initialize", "block_name", "by_reference", "choice_attr", "choice_label", "choice_loader", "choice_name", "choice_translation_domain", "choice_value", "choices", "choices_as_values", "class", "compound", "constraints", "csrf_field_name", "csrf_message", "csrf_protection", "csrf_token_id", "csrf_token_manager", "data", "data_class", "disabled", "em", "empty_data", "error_bubbling", "error_mapping", "expanded", "extra_fields_message", "group_by", "id_reader", "inherit_data", "invalid_message", "invalid_message_parameters", "label", "label_attr", "label_format", "mapped", "method", "multiple", "placeholder", "post_max_size_message", "preferred_choices", "property_path", "query_builder", "required", "translation_domain", "trim", "upload_max_size_message", "validation_groups".
```

**Code**
StaffChoiceList.php

```php
<?php
namespace Ahi\Sp\AdminBundle\Form\ChoiceList;

use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\ChoiceList\ChoiceList;
use Symfony\Component\Form\ChoiceList\LazyChoiceList;

class StaffChoiceList extends LazyChoiceList
{
    private $staffService;

    private $loginStaff;

    private $currentStaff;

    public function __construct($staffService, $loginStaff)
    {
        $this->staffService = $staffService;
        $this->loginStaff = $loginStaff;
    }

    public function setCurrentStaff($currentStaff)
    {
        $this->currentStaff = $currentStaff;
    }

    protected function loadChoiceList()
    {
        // ログインスタッフと同じショップのスタッフを取得
        $staffs = $this->staffService->getStaffByShop($this->loginStaff->getShop());

        // 現在のスタッフが(転勤などにより)取得したスタッフに含まれない場合は末尾に追加
        if ($this->currentStaff && !array_search($this->currentStaff, $staffs)) {
            $staffs[] = $this->currentStaff;
        }
        return new ChoiceList($staffs, $staffs);
    }
}
```

ArticleType.php

```
        // 投稿者
        $authorChoiceList = new StaffChoiceList($this->staffService, $options['login_staff']);
        $builder->add("author", EntityType::class, array(
            "required" => true,
            "class" => "AhiSpCommonBundle:Staff",
            "choice_list" => $authorChoiceList,   //エラー箇所
            "placeholder" => "選択してください",
        ));
// submit
        $staff = $options['login_staff'];
        if ($staff->getShop() && $staff->getShop()->getApprovalFlg()) {
            // 承認機能を使用するショップの場合
            if ($staff->isManage()) {
                // ショップ管理者 (下書き保存、承認待ち、即時投稿)
                $builder->add("draft", SubmitType::class);
                $builder->add("approvalRequest", SubmitType::class);
                $builder->add("publish", SubmitType::class);
            } else {
                // 一般スタッフ (下書き保存、承認待ち)
                $builder->add("draft", SubmitType::class);
                $builder->add("approvalRequest", SubmitType::class);
            }
        } else {
            // 本部管理画面または承認機能を使用しないショップの場合 (下書き保存、投稿)
            $builder->add("draft", SubmitType::class);
            $builder->add("publish", SubmitType::class);
        }

        // イベント処理
        $builder->addEventSubscriber(new RelatedArticlesSubscriber($this->em));
        $builder->addEventSubscriber(new TrendTagsSubscriber($this->em));
        $builder->addEventSubscriber(new ArticleStatusSubscriber());

        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) use ($authorChoiceList) {
            $article = $event->getData();
            $authorChoiceList->setCurrentStaff($article->getAuthor());
        });
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setRequired(array(
            "login_staff",
        ));
    }
```

**試したこと**
`choices`に変更したところ、下記エラーが出ます。

```
The option "choices" with value Ahi\Sp\AdminBundle\Form\ChoiceList\StaffChoiceList is expected to be of type "null" or "array" or "\Traversable", but is of type "Ahi\Sp\AdminBundle\Form\ChoiceList\StaffChoiceList".
```

**Version**
Cent OS 6.7
PHP 5.6
Symfony 3.0.9

Comment: StaffChoiceListの実装も教えてください。[こちら](https://qiita.com/issei-m/items/ebad31ce83b0be0cb54a)によるとそもそものChoiceListの実装を変更する必要があるかもしれないです。

Comment: @keitaro_so ありがとうございます。StaffChoiceList.phpを追加しました。ご指摘の通り、変更するべき箇所がありそうです。